# About vector spaces over finite fields

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, applications

I've been dabbling with matrix computations in finite fields, and I've stumbled upon a pattern that I can't understand. Perhaps someone here could shed some light on it?

So, here's what's happening: In my application, after performing certain computations, I end up with a vector (like this one from $\mathbb{Z}_5$: $(2, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1)$), whose span is of interest in my problem. There are specific coordinates in this vector that are especially meaningful for what I'm working on. When I "normalize" this vector to make one of these significant coordinates 1, the other meaningful coordinates tend to fall into this neat pattern of being either 1 or -1, modulo the field's order.

For a specific example, consider the vector mentioned earlier, with the 3rd, 5th, and 6th coordinates being of particular importance for my application. By scaling this vector by 4 to adjust the 3rd coordinate to 1, it transforms into $(3,1,1,3,4,4)$. That is, the coordinates that matter for my application always end up being 1 or -1 after this "normalization".

I've noticed this happening consistently across different scenarios and field sizes, and can't figure why is this happening.

Comment: This is not clear.  Note that the first and fourth coordinates aren't $\pm 1$.  Presumably something in the way you choose the vectors or the way you choose the interesting components is determining this.

Comment: @lulu: In the example I gave, only the 3rd, 5th and 6th are relevant in my problem.

Comment: Yes, but you *chose* those and you *chose* the vector.  Presumably you made those choices in such a way as to produce this outcome.  We have no idea how you chose them, so we can't say much  about it.

Comment: We could say more (and your question would be more on-topic) if you give a specific and explicit example of what "of interest" and "certain computations" means, and what inputs are leading to what outputs. Does your pattern *always* occur? Does it occur more often than you'd expect in a random vector subject to any obvious constraints you have (say if you know all components of interest are nonzero, the chance of three particular components behaving like this is $25\%$).

Answer (score 1):

Let $\bar{x}\in\Bbb{F}_q^n$ be a vector in a finite-dimensional vector space over a finite field. Let $x_i\in\Bbb{F}_q$ be a 'meaningful' coordinate. If $x_i\neq0$ then we can scale the vector so that the 'meaningful' coordinate equals $1$, resulting in the vector $x_i^{-1}\bar{x}\in\Bbb{F}_q^n$. This tells us absolutely nothing about the other coordinates. Also note that this scaling is not possible if $x_i=0$.

So if it turns out that certain other coordinates always scale to $\pm1$, then you are selecting your vectors in a particular way to lead to this result. In particular, you must be selecting your vectors in such a way that the meaningful coordinates are nonzero, and in such a way that for every pair of meaningful coordinates $x_i$ and $x_j$ you have either $x_i=x_j$ or $x_i=-x_j$.